# connecting a tablet to android studio on windows 7

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to android studio and have been having trouble connecting my tablet to android studio so i can test my apps. My tablet is an filemate x2 that runs on android 4.4.2 and i've changed android studio to 4.4.2 from 6.0 . My computer im using is too old so i cant run a virtual machine because of multiple issues(intel HAXM, etc) but i run on windows 7. Its an off brand tablet and i tried to find the OEM driver and thought i found something like it on Wintec(filemate's company) website but it didnt work. anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you enabled developer options and USB debugging (a.k.a. adb) on the tablet?

Comment: You need to enable developer options and USB debugging in your Android Tablet. These will be found in your settings.

Comment: yea i've enabled the developer mode on it

Comment: and usb debugging but it still cant find the device

Answer (score 0):

Many times it will not recognize the device and because of driver issues, the device won't show up.

**go to settings -> control panel -> hardware and sound -> device manager**

check for any devices showing an error. Many androids will show as an unknown USB device.

try to update the drivers for it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i figured it out. i had to download pdanet on my tablet and it was able to connect